# Typecasting from str to int inside jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I encountered a scenario where I need to fetch `numeric` data from the database and run that number of loops on my template, something like:

in my `views.py`:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_range(value):
    return range(value)

def quesSetting(request):
    questionSet_obj = questionSet.objects.filter(id = pk).first()
    quesSetting_dict = {
        'noNumeric' : questionSet_obj.noNumeric,
    }
    return render(request, 'app/quesSetting.html', quesSetting_dict)
```

my `template`:

```
{% for i in noNumeric|get_range %}
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numericQuestion" array_column="{{ i }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Now it says following `error`:

```
'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So, I try to typecast the `noNumeric` into `int` like this:

```
{% for i in int(noNumeric)|get_range %}
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numericQuestion" array_column="{{ i }}">
{% endfor %}
```

This time it gives following error:

```
Could not parse some characters: int|(noNumeric)||get_range
```

**How can I fix this issues?**

Comment: what the example output of `noNumeric` btw?

Comment: `int` value, in my test case it is: **2**

Comment: and to confirm that your custom `|get_range` is working?

Comment: yea, to confirm it I have replaced `noNumeric` with `2`, and it was working properly

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, like:

```
@register.filter
def get_range(value):
    value = int(value)
    return range(value)
```

Comment: meanwhile, I have tested your previous `get_range` function, and it worked fine. imo, why it converted to string value.

Comment: I am confused. That method also should work perfectly as far as I know. Anyway, thanks for the help @binpy !